# How to Remove alert validation in JQuery Multifile

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery multifile upload plugin http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile can able to select document but when I tried to select the wrong file it shows validation message as an alert

> You cannot select a .mp4 file.
> Try again...

Instead of an alert message, how to show a validation text message? Also, any possibilities to add "Required" validation for file using this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you [posted the question also in the plugin's Github](https://github.com/fyneworks/multifile/issues/13). While you wait for a reply from the creator(s). Here are two "hacky" options that you can go with:

1. **Modify a local version of the plugin** and remove the `alert()` towards the end of the code:

   ```
   ...
   error:function(a){"undefined"!=typeof console&&console.log(a),alert(a)}
   ...
   ```

   or replace it with the a function that will show the validation text message:

   ```
   ...
   error:function(a){"undefined"!=typeof console&&console.log(a),myFunction(a)}
   ...

   function myFunction(errorMessage) {
       // PLACE YOUR CODE HERE
   }
   ```
2. **Stop the event propagation if the file fails**: use the validation events provided by the plug-in to stop the execution of the alert (in particular the `onFileInvalid` event).

   ```
   $('#WithEvents').MultiFile({
       max: 2,
       max_size: 100,
       accept: 'jpg',
       onFileInvalid: function (element, value, master_element, event) {

           // PLACE YOUR CODE HERE

           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
       },
   });
   ```

   Truly, this `event.preventDefault()` doesn't work as it should, but it creates an error that stops the execution of the alert (I know it's not the best solution, but it kind of works).

   Also, as part of the code that you run, you'll have to reset the value of the input to an empty file or the incorrect one will still be selected (something like `$("#myInput").val("")`.

---

About making the field as required, you don't have to make changes in the plugin or anything, just indicate that your field is `required`, then thanks to the magic of HTML5 and your browser, the trick will be done:

```
<input multiple type="file" id="WithEvents" required />
```

---

You can see an example working here: http://jsfiddle.net/8ma0vmxd/ (I copied the code of the plugin directly on the JS window so you can easily see where the `alert()` is towards the end).

Comment: perfect quick solution ! i don't want to alter the plugin code, so i go with option 2. thanks